# Display microsends in sql server

Tags: sql-server

How can I display microseconds in SQL SERVER?

I have looked at the CONVERT function which has a lot of options but none with microseconds.

My column is type "datetime";

Comment: what version of SQL Server are you on?

Comment: will you need to use datetime2 to get sufficient microsecond accuracy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For microsecond precision you need to use **`DATETIME2`** datatype, there is no way around this.

`DATETIME` does not store microsecond information, it only stores data up to milisecond and even that is not precise enough down to 1 milisecond.

For a more detailed breakdown on what precision to expect from different time or datetime datatypes [have a look here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/DateTime/134800/).

Answer (score 0):

an example that seems to illustrate microsecond date arithmetic  -note use of DATETIME2 - DATETIME is not accurate even to 1ms - bear in mind SQL getdate may not return values to microsecond accuracy - I don't know where your values are from of course.

```
declare @dn as datetime2 = getdate();
waitfor delay  '00:00:01';
declare @dn2 as datetime2 = getdate();

SELECT datediff(microsecond,@dn,@dn2);
```